# Generating C# client code from a JAXB WSDL with a binding file

Tags: c#, jaxb, wsdl

I have a WSDL with dozens of XSD and I need to generate client code from the WSDL to consume a Web Service. The owner of the web service uses Java and generated the WSDL/XSD using JAXB. JAXB specifies a "binding file" for customized bindings, and the owner has generated a XJB file (JAXB customized binding file) to be used with the WSDL.

I need to generate my client code in C#, but svcutil and Visual Studio's Add Service Reference don't have any provisions for this customized bindings file. There are tools to generate Java client code that take a binding file as an argument, but no tools for C# generation. I've trying just running svcutil without specifying the XJB, but I can't get it to work. I've done extensive Google searches with no luck. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: As suggested by @Bogdan, the binding file was a red herring. My problem was with validation of namespaces with some types being declare multiple times. I am unsure if it is caused by a WSDL coming from Java (since code generation works with a Java tool but not svcutil), but the binding file does NOT appear to be needed for .Net client code generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

[You can customize WSDLs](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.1.2m1/docs/customizations.html) by providing binding declarations, but **these are Java specific and the customizations apply only while generating Java code from the WSDL**. The bindings can be declared inline (embedded in the XSD/WSDL) or within a separate file.
You have a separate file so I'm thinking the WSDL and XSDs are "clean".

**The JXB file is a red herring though. A WSDL is supposed to be technology agnostic, it doesn't care about Java, C# or whatever**. You should be able to generate the code because svcutil will just ignore the Java bindings.

What error does svcutil throw at you? I've seen it fail with hard to understand messages when the WSDL was missing a `<type>` section. You mentioned dozens of XSD files, how are they imported in the WSDL and does the import work? If you open the WSDL in Visual Studio does it show validation errors, is it complaining about something?

Finally, if everything fails, you could feed it all (including the JXB file) to a Java tool like [wsimport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) and get some Java files out of it. You can do a quick [deploy with Endpoint.publish](http://java.boot.by/ocewsd6-guide/ch08.html) and then point svcutil to the deployed address plus `?wsdl` and see if you get a different result.

Comment: I actually found a similar article describing how the binding file works and I ended up added what was in the binding file inline to the XSD files. This still didn't work. The errors are all along the line of "There was a validation error on a schema generated during export" then it describes the error. The other error is "Cannot import wsdl:portType" and then "The element 'xxx' is missing."

Comment: The WSDL imports/incudes three XSD and all the other XSDs are imported/included from those three, and those XSDs continue to import a few other XSDs, etc. I've pointed svcutil to a web server where I've set up the WSDL and XSD folder structure, b/c in the past that has seemed to work better interpreting the paths and location of the XSDs. No validation errors in Visual Studio, except ReSharper complaining on an include: "Cannot resolve the 'schemaLocation' attribute"

Comment: This looks more and more like svcutil unable to resolve all XSD imports, so you get an incomplete WSDL. Svcutil doesn't care about the Java bindings so don't include them in the WSDL, try instead to copy-paste all the XSDs in the WSDL and get just one big file with everything inside (maybe ask the person who gave you the files to give you just one WSDL instead). Then validate the WSDL before feeding it to svcutil (use a validator specifically designed for WSDLs, there are some free online available). It's likelly that it can't resolve all the files so limit the context to just one file.

Comment: Working on implementing some of your suggestions. Will get back to you tomorrow on results.

Comment: I solved the problem and, as you suggested, the binding file was a red herring, but imports was not the issue. I had to go through a lot of the schemas and change namespaces because there were duplicate declarations and collisions going on. My only guess is that Java tools don't require namespaces to be as explicitly declared as svcutil or other .Net WSDL tools do. I've accepted your answer because it moved me away from the binding file. I just ask that you highlight that fact in your answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [WSCF.blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/) and see if that is any useful in your case. Please note I am not familiar with JABX, but I am using this tool currerntly to generate code in C# from the wsdl.

Comment: I've tried WSCF.blue with no success. Thanks for the suggestion, though.